# Search not working in magento store

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

I have a problem while doing search in magento store...

**Getting following error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in
The line that is giving error is the last line in the below code:
```

**Code I used is:**

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('news_from_date')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('news_to_date');
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $code  = $store->getCode();
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');?>
<?php $_category_detail=Mage::registry('current_category');?>
<?php 
    $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_detail->getId())->getProductCount();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error that you are trying to get current category object while searching an item in the list.phtml page. This object is not available in this context.